# Education path vs educational path

Tags: adjectives

Here is my sentence.

> Teenagers are not completely mature, and they need their parents’ advice when it comes to an **education** vs **educational** path and career.

Which is correct: education path or educational path?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't meant to be interpreted as: *they need advice when it comes to an educational path and career vs. an education*? That is, "path" belongs only to the word "educational".

Comment: What are you asking?  The sentence, as written, is a mite confusing, but it "works".  Though one wonders why you think parents should advise on education and not the educational path or career.

Comment: Are you literally using *education vs educational* in your sentence? Or do you mean to say *an ____ [**education** or **educational**] path and career*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My AmE perspective

"Education path" and "career path" are both set-phrases and compound nouns that are very common. "Education path" describe the "journey" someone goes through from grade school, to high school / secondary school, and to university. It is the path one takes to pursue an education.

"Educational path," can also be used to describe a path that "serves an educational purpose" or "teaches." Although it would be clear in this context whichever you use.

### BrE perspective

According to a commentor @Steve, in BrE the always correct term would be "educational path". So make sure to take that into account when choosing between your two options given.

Comment: At least in BrE, an "education path" is an unheard of phrase and is jarring. You might say an *educational path* or an *academic path*, but not an *education path*.

Comment: I guess I will specify that I am speaking from an AmE point of view. Thank you for the info!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I believe the "vs" is being used to present two options that the OP is deciding between using: either "eduction path" OR " educational path". I do not think that OP thinks "education vs. educational path" would appear in their final sentence.

Comment: @katatahito Oh yes! Sorry. You're quite right. I've deleted it and reposted just the last bit. Thanks.

Comment: "... when it comes to choosing their education and their career" might be more elegant.

Comment: The preference for 'educational path' to 'education path' seems if anything greater in ['AmE'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=education+path%2Ceducational+path&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) than in ['BrE'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=education+path%2Ceducational+path&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), according to Google ngrams searches.